# Create a geometry with N equal sized faces

Tags: three.js

Using Three.JS, what is the easiest way to make an n-sided geometry with an arbitray number of equal sized faces?

For example you can make a cube using the `BoxGeometry`, and a octahedron using the OctahedronGeometry, but what about everything in between?

Comment: In 3D, there are only [5 Platonic Solids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platonic_solids) -- and three.js has a geometry for each of them.

Comment: Ok that's fascinating, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The 5 Platonic Solids can be rendered like so:

```
var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 10, 10, 10 );
var geometry = new THREE.TetrahedronGeometry( 10, 0 );
var geometry = new THREE.OctahedronGeometry( 10, 0 );
var geometry = new THREE.IcosahedronGeometry( 10, 0 );
var geometry = new THREE.DodecahedronGeometry( 10, 0 );
```

There is also the `BufferGeometry` version of these 5 classes.

For the material, use `shading: THREE.FlatShading` for the best look.

three.js r.85